# changing htaccess wont affect on my site

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, redirect

I'm have word-press web site and trying to change some links name of my website that wont exist in word-press and I create them manually and loaded to root. for example I wan'na load `/folder1/test.php` but show address in URL bar is something like: `/folder3`

I changed htaccess in many ways but it wont work. my last htaccess is :

```
# BEGIN WordPress


Options -MultiViews
RewriteRule folder1/purchased_users.php folder3 [R=301,L]

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]

</IfModule>


# END WordPress
```

Answer (score 0):

use your rewrite rule without a redirection:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^folder3$ folder1/purchased_users.php [L]
```